# how to transfer file to spark executor

Tags: apache-spark

I plan to extract the Kafka data using Spark. Spark cluster mode is standalone. I submitted my job using the following command

```sh
./spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.0.1 ~/Documents/3-Playground/kstream-de.py --files ~/Downloads/caroot.jks,~/Downloads/kclient.jks
```

But I got the error

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/picomy/App/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop3.2/scratch/spark-6e60fdee-7c8b-4fe0-a17c-1a4b1c547f6c/userFiles-9c3a19bd-f859-46e5-b681-1b382de75160/kclient.jks
```

spark-submit didn't transfer the files to executor in the specified directory.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is coming becuase that path is not accessible by all executores. If you use Spark in Cluster-Mode with Hadoop then you can use HDFS path. But here you are working with Standalon Spark then I will suggest to use NFS (Share Path ) that should be accessible to all executores and give NFS file path.

If you need to any help to create NFS then you can use below two link

https://www.tecmint.com/how-to-setup-nfs-server-in-linux/

https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/nfs-share